# Issues with the UIViewController and UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, ios, model-view-controller, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

Ok, i need help for this action in Table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use [-popToRootViewControllerAnimated:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/popToRootViewControllerAnimated%3a) or [-popToViewControllerAnimated:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/popToViewController%3aanimated%3a)

In your case for returning to view 1, use:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

If you want to return to a specific view controller, get it's reference and then do:

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController: specificViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Ok, i need help : How can i return a specific view controller ? I don't find a solution by myself...

Comment: use the `viewControllers`'s property of your `UINavigationController`. VC are ordered in the array, select one by index, and then call `- (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated;`.

Comment: Thanks Vince. Just wanna throw another comment in here that Martin should call - (void)popToViewController:(UIViewController*)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated; instead of - (void)pushViewController

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Storyboard...

Create a Segue pointing to View1 VC and perform that Segue when the Back button is triggered.

If not, Sid's answer is correct.